Estne in lingua Latina verbum quod significat abire ex schola sine finiendo, ut Anglica phrasa "drop out" vel Croaticum verbum "ispisati"?
Estne in lingua Latina verbum quod significat abire ex schola sine finiendo, ut Anglica phrasa "drop out" (cessare-prehendere foras) vel Croaticum verbum "is-pisati" (ex-scribere)?
Exempli gratia, si loquar "Utinam numquam incepissem in hac universitate studere. Omnis ea mathematica me occidit. Numquam potero hanc scholam finire, solummodo ex ea cum mala fama abibo.", ego probabiliter... quid agam?

Si licet de Latinitate aliqua dicere: (1) "phrasa" non est verbum Latinum. "phrasis" in nonnullis scriptoribus invenitur, carens autem significatione verbi Anglici "phrase." (2) non licet uti "sine + gerundium ablativum" ad significandum "without + verb-ing." Vide hoc rogatum. (3) "Dicam" loco verbi "loquar" utendum mihi videtur.

Traupman translates the noun "drop-out" as destitor de schola. If I had to turn that into a verb, I'd go with de schola desistere.

Are you sure you mean Traupman? I found it in the "silva" of the "Lexicon Morganium," which lists Levine's 1967 Latin Dictionary as the source.

Yes. I found it in the English-to-Latin section of his pocket dictionary.
